# Why doesn't my Gmail photo change?

Tags: gmail, google-plus

I have changed my Google+ photo 6 months ago. I even removed my old photo from the list of profile photos to be sure the old photo is gone.

I even changed my photo in Gmail → *Settings* → *My picture*.

The Gmail photo on my phone hasn't changed even now. When I call people with smartphones, they see my old photo on the screen. On the mobile Gmail app I see my old Gmail photo next to my emails.

Comment: Have you tried selecting _No Picture_ from the Gmail options and see what happens?

Comment: nope. doesn't work :( still see my old picture.

Comment: Note that on your phone it might be cached in the contacts app.

Comment: when does it automatically clear out the cache? I can clear out mine, but what about other people's phones?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea.

Comment: Have you also changed the visibility to _Visible to everyone_ in Gmail?

Comment: @Alex, yes... :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the clue in "When I call people with smartphones, they see my old photo on the screen."

When you call me, I expect my phone to show me the picture of you from my contacts book, not from your profile.    Granted, when I set you up in my contacts the first time, it's possible that the initial values were taken from your Google profile.   But after that, I'd expect updates to my data about you only when I choose, not when you do.

Comment: it's not just that. Even on my GMail phone app. I see my old photo in a thumbnail next to my emails.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Profile picture under your Gmail 'Contact' page. If the picture seems to be old one then try changing it.

[image]

Else, try changing it in 'Google+' and check your results. Click on '+you' in the top of your gmail page and change the profile picture.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope. Tried both. No results.

Comment: Did you clear the browser cache's and checked. Also, try with different browser.

Comment: I checked it on my phone, on other peoples' phones too. so that can't be the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Kindly delete cookies from your browser, then the picture will changed. I have tried it.